# How to pass a template class as a function argument without C7568 error

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, template-classes

C++ newbie here. I'm pretty sure there's an easy and obvious solution to this problem, but even after reading through dozens of similar Q&As here, I haven't got closer to it. But here's my problem:

I have a template class:

```
template<class T>
struct KalmanSmoother
{
   Eigen::MatrixX<T> P;
   ...
   KalmanSmoother(int dynamParams, int measureParams, int controlParams = 0);
   ...
}
```

And I can use it without any problem, like this:

```
KalmanSmoother<float> smoother(4, 2);
smoother.P = Eigen::Matrix4f {
   {0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f},
   {0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f},
   {0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f},
   {0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f}
};
...
```

Works like charm. But when I want to refactor my code and I extract the initialization part into an other function, the compiler (MSVC 19.31.31104.0) starts crying. The function extraction looks like this:

```
// Declaration in the header:
void setupKalmanSmoother(KalmanSmoother<float> & smoother);

// Definition in the .cpp
inline void Vehicle::setupKalmanSmoother(KalmanSmoother<float> & smoother)
{
   smoother.P = Eigen::Matrix4f {
      {0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f},
      {0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f},
      {0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f},
      {0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f}
   };
   ...
}
```

And I'd just like to call it like this:

```
KalmanSmoother<float> smoother(4, 2);
setupKalmanSmoother(smoother);
```

Nothing magical. It should be working (I suppose...), but I get this compiler error:

```
error C7568: argument list missing after assumed function template 'KalmanSmoother'
```

The error message points to the declaration in the header. It's worth to mention that all function definitions of the template class are in the header file, since I have already run into - I think - exactly the same error when out of habit I put the definitions into the .cpp file.

So what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: No one's hopped in and answered yet, so I'm jumping to the assumption that it's not something trivial that you and I just aren't seeing. I recommend crafting a [mre] so we can poke at the problem. Maybe run it through a couple of other compilers to see if there's a difference or better compiler error.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! I'm gonna do that.

Comment: "How to pass a template class as a function argument" has multiple problems, chiefly because it seems to mix templates, classes and objects. You instantiate a _class template_ to get a _class type_, and you instantiate a (class) _type_ to get an _object_. You can pass an object as a _function argument_. But here MSVC is talking about an argument to an assumed _function template_. That's weird; `KalmanSmoother` is a _class template_.  (And it means the "argument" it's missing is a templat argument. Agree with @user4581301: we need a reproducible example.

Comment: Also, as a trivial workaround: `KalmanSmoother<float> smoother {4, 2};`.

Comment: More fishy stuff: `// Definition in the .cpp
inline void Vehicle::setupKalmanSmoother(KalmanSmoother<float> & smoother)`. The `inline` in the .cpp is suspect, and suggests a lack of understanding what `inline` actually does (bypasses ODR). And `Vehicle::` means it's a class member function, yet the call `setupKalmanSmoother(smoother); shows no `Vehicle` object.

Answer (score 1):

I got a very similar error. In my case it was due to circular #includes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when creating a datamember of a templated class.

```
    List<Graphics::RenderObject*> m_RenderObjects;
```

The fix in my instance was I needed to scope into the namespace that the 'List<>' was in.

```
    STD::List<Graphics::RenderObject*> m_RenderObjects;
```

Instead of saying 'List' is undefined, it gave me error 7568.  Which is misleading.  I recommend checking for similar issues.